# Laravel 10 modal 404

Tags: laravel

I would like to ask, I have a modal that I want to show when you press on the edit brush but when I press it I get a 404 error

I am using Laravel 10 but I always get the 404 error

Controllers:

```
public function show($id) {

    // $administradores = Administradores::finOrfail($id);

    // return view("administradores.creacion")->with(['id'=>$id]);

    $administrador = Administradores::where("id", $id)->get();

        $administradores = Administradores::all();

    if(count($administrador) != 0){

      return view("administradores.asdasd", array("status"=>200, "administrador"=>$administrador,  "administradores"=>$administradores));
    
    }else{ 

      return view("administradores.asd", array("status"=>404,  "administradores"=>$administradores));
    }
  }
```

Route

```
 Route::resource('/', 'AdministradoresController')->only('index','show','edit','post');
```

View

```
<a href="{{ route('administradores.show', [$value->id])}}" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">
                            <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt text-white"></i>
                          </a>
```

Comment: the first argument to `resource` is a name, it is not a path ... you have just created routes with no named route parameter (`/` isn't a name) ... also there is no `post` for resource routing